# `\ref` not working in a sub .tex file within the document class revtex4-2

Tags: cross-referencing

I find the `\ref` not working in a sub .tex when I use the document class revtex4-2.
Here is the code in the main.tex

```
\documentclass[ reprint, amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-2}
 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\include{sub}

\end{document}
```

And the code in sub.tex file

```
\section{$\alpha$}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:abc}
e^{i\pi}=-1
\end{equation}
Euler (\ref{eq:abc})
```

The `\ref` generates (??) no matter how many times I compile the file. However it works when I change the document class as `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`.

How should I fix the problem of `\ref` under `\documentclass[ reprint, amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-2}`?  By the way, I use texlive2020 and I find there is no problem when I compile the file on overleaf.

Comment: can't you update to a current texlive?

Comment: Ahh, so it is a problem due to texlive rather than the document class, right?

Comment: it is quite probably a problem with the class (but I can't reproduce and without a log it is not possible to know which version you actually use). If your revtex version is older than `2020/10/03 4.2e` you could also try to update only your texlive 2020, but 2020 is already three years old, so  installing a newer texlive is something to consider anyway.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the problem with TeXLive 2019, where the version of revtex4-2 is 4.2c, but not on my installation of TeXLive 2020, where I have 4.2e.  There's also no problem on TeXLive 2023, with v. 4.2f of revtex4-2.

Comment: Thanks! That helps